# When entering the United States as a permanent resident and with Global Entry, does the US immigration agent stamp one's passport?

Tags: usa, passports, passport-stamps, global-entry

When entering the United States as a permanent resident and with Global Entry, does the US immigration agent stamp one's passport?

---

Follow-up question: [Why do US officers sometimes stamp non-US passports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168838/1810)

Comment: As a side note: Even with VWP and Global Entry, last time i didn't get a stamp, just the second receipt which contained all necessary data (admitted date etc.).

Answer (score 6):

No. Reference my passport, which has no stamp for my return to California after spending last Christmas in England. I am a permanent resident and used Global Entry.

My entry is recorded in the CBP [travel history database](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search), so there is an official record, just not in my passport.

My experience was arriving at San Diego International Airport (SAN).

Comment: Confirmed. They haven't even _looked_ at my passport the last dozen times.

Comment: @Aganju That matches my experience. I've stopped having my passport out when arriving in the US.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, I did receive a stamp in my passport when pre-clearing with CBP in Halifax (YHZ) with NEXUS using the Global Entry kiosk. They did look at my passport, ask me how I gained my Permanent Residence, and stamped my passport with an entry stamp.

Comment: Looks like different places may be different, so I've added the airport to my answer.